# How to add <b> tag to the text after searching in WebBrowser with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webbrowser-control

What I've tried is I can output the full text search. More than that, I would like to add a `<b>` tag to each keyword after searching as an image below.

[image: Pic]

**The textbox has all lower characters as `tran thi dao`. However, what I would like here is add `<b>` tag to the result as `Tran Thi Dao`.**

### [image: Pic]

```
private string GetBodyText()
{
    StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\rsc-app2k8\Applications\RSC_HR_Documents\", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
    {
    string settext = GetTextFromPDF(filePaths[i]).Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\t", " ");
    string searchText = tbSearch.Text;
    int prefix = 50, postfix = 50;
    int index = settext.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    if (index >= 0)
        {
            string foundText = settext.Substring(index, searchText.Length);
            int contextStart = Math.Max(0, index - prefix);
            int contextLength = Math.Min(settext.Length - contextStart, searchText.Length + prefix + postfix);
            string contextText = settext.Substring(contextStart, contextLength);
            string files = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]);
            //MessageBox.Show(contextText);
            strB.AppendFormat("<img src='" + pdficon + "' /> <a href='{0}'>{1}</a></br><b>{2}</b> {3}<br></br>", filePaths[i], files, foundText, contextText);
        }
    }
    return strB.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the initDoc() method that you are calling in your search button's click event?

Comment: @Sam There is only GetBodyText() to go

Comment: Try this this.webBro.DocumentText = this.webBro.DocumentText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim() + "</ b>");

Comment: So, instead of initDoc() you'd use GetBodyText(), right?

Comment: @Sam That's correct. All are in GetBodyText()

Comment: Ok then the simplest solution would be this instead of my initial suggestion use this just before MessageBox.Show(contextText); line in your GetBodyText() method. contextText = contextText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim() + "</ b>");

Comment: @Sam I think it must be `string foundText = settext.Substring(index, searchText.Length);`, but I don't know how to put `foundText` into `strB.AppendFormat("<img src='" + pdficon + "' /> <a href='{0}'>{1}</a></br>{2}<br></br>", filePaths[i], files, contextText);`.

Comment: See my reply just before yours

Comment: @Sam Please take a look on my thread. I've edited the code and added one more image with some notes to make it more understandable.

Comment: You still didn't do what I suggested. Try that first. contextText = contextText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "</ b>");

Comment: @Sam I've tried but nothing happened then. There was no weight style bold() for any text.

Comment: But I can't see what you've tried. Can you update the question with the code you tried?

Comment: Why don't I try with that? However, the truth is that I did it but there was nothing.

Comment: I want to see the GetBodyText() method with the change I suggested to give you further instructions

Comment: Is that correct? If yes, there was nothing happen with weight style bold(). `string contextText = settext.Substring(contextStart, contextLength);
string files = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]);
contextText = contextText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "</ b>");
//MessageBox.Show(contextText);
strB.AppendFormat("<img src='" + pdficon + "' /> <a href='{0}'>{1}</a></br>{2}<br></br>", filePaths[i], files, contextText);`

Comment: So you didn't try this. Note there's .ToLower() being called there. This will capture all words you search. contextText = contextText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "</ b>");

Comment: I've added already. Please take a look on this part above. `string files = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]); contextText = contextText.Replace(tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower(), "<b>" + tbSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "</ b>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `Regex` to solve this problem? You can search while ignoring the case, and replace the search term in the original format with your `<b>` tags.

For example:

```
var searchTerm = "bird";
var input = "Hey the bird flew over there. BIRD!";

var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, searchTerm, match =>
{
    return String.Format("<b>{0}</b>", match);
}, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This should give the following result: `Hey the <b>bird</b> flew over there. <b>BIRD</b>!`

Comment: That's awesome. This addressed my issue now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good work! I've got the concept right but used the wrong function (String.Replace) :)